# What kind of a space is $\mathbb{C}_{-1}$?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, grand-unification

In the first paragraph on page 24 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1556, it's written

> the left-handed leptons $\nu_L$ and $e^−_L$ both have hypercharge $Y=−1$, so each one spans a copy of $\mathbb{C}_{-1}$:
> $$\nu_L \in \mathbb{C}_{-1},\quad e^−_L\in \mathbb{C}_{-1}$$

What kind of a space is $\mathbb{C}_{-1}$? I understand that $\mathbb{C}^2\cong \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$. But I can't figure out what $\mathbb{C}_{-1}$ is.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a non-standard notation for $\mathbb{C}$ carrying the representation of the hypercharge $\mathrm{U}(1)$ labeled by $Y=-1$.

Comment: Thanks. In the table on page 22, the SU(2) representation of the right-handed fermions has been denoted by a simple $\mathbb{C}$. But in the table on page 24 the U(1) representation has been denoted using the subscript notation. Any particular reason for using these two different kinds of notation for denoting $\mathbb{C}$?